# Android Studio 3.4 freezing on loading project after upgrading from Android Studio 3.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

After upgrading from Android Studio 3.3 to 3.4 I'm stuck unable to get past "loading project" and eventually entire android studio becomes just a blank/grey empty screen, using about 650mb ram doing nothing, but guess that's normal for java :D

Seems to me somebody really jumped the gun on this 3.4, didn't expect this much headache with an upgrade from supposedly the stable branch.

I tried deleting gradle folder from inside project and didn't help.

Comment: Please provide more info on dependencies and gradle configuration you've used in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well nothing I tried fixed it, until I remembered it was limited internet with proxy and even though Android Studio did not complain at all about unable to get something but just got stuck/froze on loading project, I found out from proxy logs that it was trying to download things from d.android.com which previous versions of A-Studio didn't use.

Once d.android.com was allowed through proxy, Android Studio 3.4 finally loaded up fine.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem on macOS with LitteSnitch (firewall). After I allowed access in LittleSnitch it was working again.

Comment: @kasimir Great, glad it helped someone else! Now I feel ok marking it as accepted answer. I hate how so much software now "silently" dies when it can't access internet when it tries. I got a ton of Apple XCODE errors mysteriously and discovered it was because it couldn't "call home"! Previously Intel Haxm similarly failed without hint, and was due to wanting internet even for a self-contained install file. We need to "complain" more so companies stop forcing "call home" internet snooping down our throats. At least they should disclose upfront any network/Internet access needed.